# apostrophe in BI Publisher

Tags: bi-publisher

I am working on a rtf file which displays data based on an xml source file.
XML Source File:

```
...
<XMLElement>Something</XMLElement>
...
```

In the rtf file, I have a checkbox that I want to check for a specific value.

For example, if I want the box to be checked if value = 'Something', I use the following condition in BI Publisher properties tab of the checkbox (which works):

```
<?XMLElement='Something'?>
```

My question is: How can I do this if the value from the XML contains a single quotation mark ( ' )
For example, you can replace string 'Something' with string 'I don't know'

```
<XMLElement>Don&apos;t know</XMLElement>
```

PS: I cannot alter the XML file and i have to do this in the rtf template.

Thanks!

Comment: The only thing I found browsing is this:

https://www.jdelist.com/vb4/showthread.php/50397-apostrophe-in-BI-Publisher

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried:
`<?XMLElement="I don't know"?>`

I've found that some of the code can use either single- or double-quotes.

For example, we have a fully-functioning report that has been in production for some time in which you can find the following statements (some details changed for security):

```
<?when: XMLElement != "ABC"?>  
<?if:$p_BusUnitCode != "XYZ"?>
```

Comment: I have checked your solution and it really works. Thanks.